# Is there a way to apply project.yaml changes on deployment?

Tags: craft3, projectconfig

Love the new new project config functionality, but if there are changes that need to be synchronised the site essentially goes down until the changes are applied manually.

I wondered if anyone had a simple way to programmatically apply the changes automatically when the site is deployed, via a webhook?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a script to use the craft executable to sync your project config file

```
./craft project-config/sync
```

Comment: At the end of my deploy script I now run this series of commands: `./craft migrate/all
./craft project-config/sync
./craft clear-caches/all`

Comment: Nice I didn't even consider there's be cli commands for this!

Comment: This requires the migrationassistant plugin

Answer (score 3):

`project-config/sync` has been renamed to `project-config/apply`.
Thus you would have to run:

```
./craft project-config/apply
```